# How can I get something from python while it is showing the results but I get nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7, weekday

```
df['weekday']=df['date'].dt.day_name()
```

It was reading data from excel, I transform the date to weekday successfully, the results is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JQMM.png)

I want get 'Thursday', I have tried `df['weekday'].loc['Thursday']` and it was shown `KeyError: 'Thursday'`

How can I get 'Thursday' ? Can anyone point out where I may be missing a step?

Comment: `df['weekday'][df['weekday'] == 'Thursday']`?

Comment: it is okay, I can get all Thursday！thanks for your help.